# PHP - Regex not working.

Tags: php, regex

***Data***

`<a href='pears.php?id=358&nllist=3'><img style='border:0px;' title='Permanent Suitors' src='/pic/mockup/permyes.png' /></a>        </td>
        <td class="noborder" align="left"  valign="center">1</td>`

**Value to be extracted**

In

```
valign="center">1</td>
```

I want to extract that 1.

**Regex I'm using**

```
$pattern = '~title=\'Permanent\s*Suitors\'\ssrc=\'/pic/mockup/permyes.png\'\s/></a>\s*</td>\s*<td class="noborder"\salign="left"\s*valign="center">(.*?)</td>~';
```

But its not working. Please note that I want to start the regex from "Permanent Suitors" as its the only unique thing.

Just using `<td class="noborder" align="left"  valign="center">1</td>` or starting regex from there won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should look into HTML parsers also, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in particular

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex

```
title='Permanent\s*Suitors'\K.*?\bvalign="center">(.*?)<\/td>
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/15)

```
$re = "/title='Permanent\\s*Suitors'\\K.*?\\bvalign=\"center\">(.*?)<\\/td>/m";
$str = "<a href='pears.php?id=358&nllist=3'><img style='border:0px;' title='Permanent Suitors' src='/pic/mockup/permyes.png' /></a> </td> <td class=\"noborder\" align=\"left\" valign=\"center\">1</td>\n";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```